# how to play a mp4 video in Native VideoView of android from raw folder

Tags: android

Do I have to change the file type? Because when I watch youtube vids I noticed that all the icons have a question mark, while mine has like a text file.

[image]
[image]

Comment: android studio doesn't support playing videos, if you want to view it you should use any media player.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this and check more here about **[VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)**

```
VideoView vidview = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
vidview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
vidview.start();
```

Comment: already did that. Turns out that i had to delete the .mp4 int the text files in the FILE REGISTRATION

Answer (score 0):

use this line in the java code under declaration

```
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please consider using the special code notation to separate your code from your text.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/2648551) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!